# Retro fit led ghosting

Tags: electrical

First off I apologize if I’ve made any protocol mistakes here as this is my first post.

My problem is exactly what Damon posted in 2019 (link below). He didn’t state what dimmer he had however. I have the Lutron Caseta dimmer PD-5NE which I have connected to neutral as required, only connecting just 1 retrofit LED. I have also connected the LUT-MLC capacitor up in the recessed LED can by splicing it with Wagos into the 2 LED wire connectors, and I'm still getting ghosting when the dimmer is switched off.

I haven’t tried covering the 2 metal arms with electrical tape as he did but there is no ghosting until the moment I touch the LED rim to push up to install into the can—then the ghosting begins. My LEDs are also Feit but have tried others that Lutron recommends per their website and still had ghosting on those.

I’m surprised this still happens in 2023 as Damon had back in 2019. Any advice is greatly appreciated. Thank you all in advance.

[Retro fit can light ghosting](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/171033/retro-fit-can-light-ghosting/171066)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some LED bulbs contain phosphors to help reduce flickering when dimmed down. I've seen one of those glow faintly for a surprisingly long time. Does the "ghost" effect continue if you unscrew the bulb, or does it stop immediately?

Comment: Yes the ghosting stops immediately. Some Other sites that I’ve read suggest that since I’m only using the dimmer for only 1 LED that it’s not enough current to eliminate the ghosting. However if I just put a regular dimmable LED or incandescent bulb there’s no ghosting.